# How would you describe the 3d shapes formed by the 6 or 18 neighbors of a cell in a cell latice? (Picture included)

Tags: geometry

Is there a name for this shape/geometry? If nothing comes to mind, how you would describe the shapes?

[Image of 18-connected shape, or 18 neighboring cells of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUezV.png) -- [original source url](https://images.app.goo.gl/yd5bY5357s8QVc6F8)

[Image of 6-connected shape, or 6 orthogonal neighbors of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kvow.png) -- [original source url](https://images.app.goo.gl/8NnZcpvjSnymnj4x8)

(The best descriptions that come to mind are "3d plus shapes", "the plus's or edge cubes of a rubix cube", "the 6 center faces of a rubix cube").

(*edited to include "orthogonal" in descriptions of what I'm talking about based on helpful comment*).

Comment: I's call the second set "the orthogonal neighbors" of the pixel.

Comment: Hmmm... Googling, `"the second set of orthogonal neighbors"` yielded no results, but, I did run into this!: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-neighboring-points-around-a-cell-in-an-orthogonal-lattice-In-the-left-most-diagram_fig3_51676897. So the 6 connected set/shape could perhaps be called the "von Neumann neighborhood of points around a cell in an orthogonal lattice" or something. The word "orthogonal" was pretty key and definitely gets me on the right track. I'll probably take an attempt at writing an answer tonight but if you want to make your comment an answer go for it :+1:

Comment: I was surprized to see that your "3D greek cross" (personal naming) could fill the space (https://circlesandtrianglesblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/06/three-dimensional-tessellation/)

Comment: I met the first shape in this brain teaser : https://www.davans.com/martenvankammen.html but no name for it...

Comment: The convex hull of the "3D greek cross" is a "small rhombicuboctahedron" from which we could say (?) it is its "skeleton".

Comment: The second one is one of 1023 heptacubes. It appears as x33b on image 6 [here](http://recmath.org/PolyPages/PolyPages/Heptacubes/index.htm?7cubesframes.htm). It doesn't seem to have a specific name.

Comment: It is a version of the hypercube. See page 18 of this document http://www.symmetrie.info/downloads/begleittext_symmetrie_ausstellung.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Based on helpful links and advice in the comments section, here are some suggested answers:

For the 6-connected shape:

- The von Neumann neighborhood of cells around a point in an orthogonal lattice. See [neighboring points](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-neighboring-points-around-a-cell-in-an-orthogonal-lattice-In-the-left-most-diagram_fig3_51676897)
- The set of orthogonal neighbors to a cell/pixel in three dimensions
- The set of 6-connected pixels to a pixel in 3d space. See [pixel connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity)

For the 18-connected shape:

- The set of 18-connected pixels to a pixel in 3d space. See [pixel connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity)
- ???

Comment: I am sorry but your answer doesn't contain any added information compared with the title of the question.